# Javascript event listener confuses me

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm confused. I want to construct a gallery wherein you can click on any image and you have the full-scale image superimposed on the document (kinda like with facebook galleries).

The gallery's thumbnails are displayed with some PHP. It looks like this:

```
$i = 0;

while($img_dir = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gallery_q))
{
    $i++;

    echo
    '
        <div class="entry"><div class="image" id="' . $img_dir['dir'] . '">
<img id="img' . $i . '" src="' . $img_dir['thumb_dir'] . '" /></div></div>
    ';

}
```

I then fetch the number of images with json_encode and produce a bunch of event listener with a loop, like so:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= nbImg; i++)
{ 
    document.getElementById("img" + i).addEventListener("click", display(i));
}
```

The display function being the following:

```
function display(i)
{
document.getElementById("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin",
'<div id="display"><div><img src="' + document.getElementById("img" + i).parentNode.getAttribute("id") + '"></div>');

style.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
"#display{z-index: 20; position: fixed; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; left: 50%; top: 10%; margin-left: -600px;");

}
```

And well, it works.. except display() is called without any regards for whether I click on the image or not. But when I restrain this behavior to only one image (that is, the event listener isn't in a loop and no argument is passed to the function; it just displays a preset image) then all is fine. The event is triggered when I click.

It's actually not the first time I encounter this phenomenon of the listening function being triggered not matter what event I ask the event listener to be on the lookout for. It happens most often with alert and I honestly can't figure out why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign the function like that. Adding the `()` immediately invokes the function (to pass the function, omit the `()` - but you'll also lose the ability to pass `i` in, `event` would instead be passed in since it's the first param that the function passed to `addEventListener` has):

```
document.getElementById("img" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {
    display(i);
});
```

You'll probably notice that `i` is always the last iterated loop var, so you want to wrap this in a closure:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= nbImg; i++) { 
    (function(i) {
        document.getElementById("img" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {
            display(i)
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the reason display is being called has to do with this code.  you're invoking the display function as opposed to referencing it.  replace the display function with a closure.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= nbImg; i++) {
  document.getElementById("img" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {
    display(i)
  });
}
```

Comment: You've explained the issue correctly. What about the solution?

Comment: Thanks, it works and I now understand the underlying principle

Comment: your welcome.  if you're new to javascript, i'd recommend reading up on closures and scope because problems like this can and will pop up frequently.